# Google PlayStore Api - python library access

Tags: python, google-play-developer-api

Is there a default python library to access Google PlayStore API?
I'm looking to query a list of internal users from my PlayStore apps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link for python package to scrape details from google play store.

https://pypi.org/project/google-play-scraper/

It is working perfectly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But using this scraper seems like i can't get a list of users from a specific app, just the app details, reviews and so on.